# Break; My final break; gives me an :Unreachable statement error, any clue why?

Tags: java, break

```
DecimalFormat neat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean yes = (true);
do{
int quarter;

while (true) {
System.out.print("Enter number of quarters (1-10): ");
if (keyboard.hasNextInt() && (quarter = keyboard.nextInt()) >= 1 && quarter <= 10)
break;
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10");
              }
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have " + quarter + " quarters.");

double intrestRate;
while (true) {
System.out.print("Enter interest rate (5%-25%), without percent sign: ");
if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (intrestRate = keyboard.nextDouble()) >= 5 && intrestRate <= 25)
break;
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
System.out.println("Interest rate must be between 5% and 25%");
             }
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have selected a " + intrestRate + "% rate of interest.");


double balance;
while (true) {
System.out.print("Enter beginning principal balance, that is greater than zero: $");
if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (balance = keyboard.nextDouble()) > 0);
break;
keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print("Beginning balance must be greater than zero.");
             }
```

Been working on this code for about three days, I have three variations im experimenting with. This is by far my favorite and most complex yet more efficient than the rest. *with help of others. But why would I be getting this : Unreachable statement error?

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: You have an extra `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int the last while loop you have

```
    if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (balance = keyboard.nextDouble()) > 0);
```

**and the semicolon at the end of the expression** causes error - you have an empty **if body** there and the break that (I guess) should be under condition fireing every time making the end code unreachable

Comment: *Face Palm* I've been working on this for too long, little things are passing me up. I'm running into some VERY confusing logic errors.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find the answer fitting your question you can accept it.

Comment: It does, But, I have another question. I'll edit the code real fast okay?

Comment: you should not **change** the whole question! just add an edit like "EDIT: after fixing bug new problem has appeared..." at the end - or make a new one if the question is completely not related to this one

Comment: @Dillon Most IDEs can automatically format/indent Java code. If you had done that, the problem would have jumped out at you immediately.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Okay thanks! I appreciate the input. Its been a long day with me and this here code :/ Never frustrated just wishing to find a solution! I have everything working properly, but if you look at my prevously asked questions I'm trying to make the code repeat the loops if the user inputs No. But all my attempts have led to some VERY confusing logic errors.